# Jacobian Criterion from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb P^n(\mathbb R)$

Tags: projective-space, affine-geometry, inverse-function-theorem, jacobian

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}
\renewcommand\P{\mathbb{P}}$
$\newcommand\pd[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
Let $f:\R^n\rightarrow \P^n(\R)$ be smooth, then why can one apply the inverse function theorem on $f$ at $\vec{x}\in\R^n$ iff 
the matrix (evaluated at $\vec{x}$)
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\pd{f_0}{x_1} & \pd{f_0}{x_2} & \dots & \pd{f_0}{x_n} & f_0\\[2ex] 
\pd{f_1}{x_1} & \pd{f_1}{x_2} & \dots & \pd{f_1}{x_n} & f_1\\[2ex] 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\[2ex] 
\pd{f_n}{x_1} & \pd{f_n}{x_2} & \dots & \pd{f_n}{x_n} & f_n\\[2ex] 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has a non-zero determinant? Here: coordinates in the affine space are numbered $1$ to $n$ and in the projective space from $0$ to $n$, and $f(\vec x)=[f_0(\vec x):\ldots:f_n(\vec x)]$
for real valued infinitely differentiable functions $f_i$ ($i=0,\dots,n$).
I understand the case between two affine spaces and between two projective spaces (Jacobian criterion?) but I do not get this one.

Comment: I think I get it now. But I'll let others give it a try. You have to go down to the canonical charts and check that the rank is $n$ using each chart. Then show that if you add the extra column with $f_i$ you get an extra linearly independent column for the Jacobian on each chart. This is useful, as you do not then need to think about the charts using this $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix.